# importing txt file into tuple within dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data structure in a `.txt` file set up as follows:

```
andrew
3 3 1 0 3 0 3 0 0 -3 0 5 3 0 1 0 0 5 3 0 0 0 0 1 0 3 0 1 0 0 3 5 3 3 0 
0 0 5 0 5 0 3 3 0 -3 0 0 5 1 5 3 0 3 0 0
```

I'm trying to import it as in this format:

```
{'user':[0,1,3,4,5]}
```

I've tried various implementations, but can't find anything to suit my needs and account for so many variables.

My current code is as follows:

```
    with open('ratings.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        x = line.split()
        print(x)
        ratings[x[0]] = [y for y in x[1:]])
```

Any idea on how to improve the code, please?

Comment: `{'user':[0,1,3,4,5]}` it is your expected output?

Comment: Yeah that's how I want the dictionary to be structured. The name should be a key and the values should be a list/tuple.

Answer (score 0):

you can read the whole file by `read()` method then split it so that you can create the dict as you want with out reading line by line

```
ratings = {}
with open('ratings.txt', 'r') as f:
    X = f.read().split()

    x = set([int (i) for i in X[1:] if int(i) >= 0]) # this will create a set which values are >= 0

    ratings[X[0]] = list(x) 


print(ratings)# output --> {'andrew': [0, 1, 3, 5]}
```

this is assuming your text file will always be in the format you mention above only one user at a time

As per Your text File I think you can do like this :
you read 2 lines by 2 to until you find a empty line or the end of file
like below

```
ratings = {}
with open('ratings.txt', 'r') as f:
    while True:
        name = f.readline().strip()
        values = f.readline().strip().split()
        #print(values)
        if not name: break
        else:
            ratings[name] = list(set(int (i) for i in values if int(i) >= 0))

print(ratings)# output --> {'andrew': [0, 1, 3, 5]}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, unfortunately I'm getting the same error

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Moose'

Comment: can there be more than one user in the text file?

Comment: Does you text file `andrew
3 3 1 0 3 0 3 0 0 -3 0 5 3 0 1 0 0 5 3 0 0 0 0 1 0 3 0 1 0 0 3 5 3 3 0
0 0 5 0 5 0 3 3 0 -3 0 0 5 1 5 3 0 3 0 0
moose
3 4 5 6 0 6 2 4 2 5 3 6 8 54 3` like this ?

Comment: Yeah sorry there's loads of users. I was only trying to show the structure. The full program is visible here

https://repl.it/@glasgowm1498/CoralTangibleWamp

Comment: I added some edit you cane read untill end of file  an then you can check if name is not there break the loop else create the key values and add to the `ratings` you'll get a out pull like this `{'Cust6': [0, 1, 3, 5], 'Moose': [0, 1, 3, 5], 'Ben': [0, 1, 3, 5], 'Cust7': [0, 1, 3, 5], 'andrew': [0, 1, 3, 5], 'Jim C': [0, 1, 3..........`

Comment: Thank you so much! This also appears to remove all duplicate numbers though? Hopefully shouldn't be too much difficulty to fix!

Comment: `set(int (i) for i in values if int(i) >= 0)` from this line we get all the values >0 and with duplicates then put inside a `set()`,  a python set cannot have duplicate values so it gives set of non duplicate values then just passing that set to `list()` will give you a list of non duplicate values fro given values in the text .thats what `list(set(int (i) for i in values if int(i) >= 0))` do